# Making a Facebook API

Tags: ruby, facebook, api

First off let me state this is HOMEWORK for school. I am looking for general ideas and direction, not "this is exactly what to write". We did not really cover API's so I am trying to learn as I go.

I have been asked to design an API that can be used with Facebook, for things like posting on my feed or adding new friends. I have been doing tutorials online and most seem to have me add some "ruby gem" that has whatever websites methods and stuff. For example I did a Twilio.com demo that needed require 'twilio-ruby' and a twitter one that needed require 'twitter'. To my understanding, these are "gems" and not "API's" correct? That being said, is Koala an API or a simply a gem that contains the methods I need for writing an API (specifically for Facebook)? If I were to use Koala and it was an API, I feel that would sort of defeat the purpose of writing an API (just reusing their methods and such).

Any other ruby API Facebook help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/other-sdks Koala is listed as "other" SDK, meaning that it provides a wrapper around the low-level Facebook Graph API requests. So, no, it's not an own (web) API IMHO.

In a narrower interpretation, an API is just an "application programming interface". This would not necessarily have to deal with being accessible for example via a REST interface. I think it depends on the definition of *API*, respectively what you professor expects. If this is unclear, I'd check back with him/her.

Check

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Api
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_API
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer